# Set data attribute value in iframe that has cross origin

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So I am going to be brutally honest about my motive. I am using one of the many video streaming sites out there...it has great quality content, however it has tons of popups and it doesn't work when my ad-blocker is on.

I have been trying to disable the ads when I load the page, but I am unable to set values of the attributes inside of the iframes.

I can select the iframe itself using:

```
window.frames[x]
```

However once I try and do anything example

```
window.frames[1].getElementByClassName('classname').length
```

I get an error in the console log that says

```
Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin 
"http://url.com"   from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

Any suggestions on how I can circumvent this? I have seen similar posts, but most people are trying to interact with the iframe they are using on their own sites, I want to use a chrome extension to inject the js onload for the site I am accessing.

I imagine the reason I cannot do this has to do with security restrictions, but I figured it was worth a shot asking.

Comment: you could use postMessage

Comment: can you give an example of that?

Comment: Im also waiting for @DanielA.White :) because I havent done this with a page that you dont have control over.. 

Yes it is for security reasons.

Comment: Doesn't the Post Message need both sides to relax their security for each other still?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to setup your own local proxy server and use that to inject your JavaScript into their page.